# Capturing hash tag values in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We want to capture aggregated, anonymous search query history for analytic purposes to improve our internal search engine performance and metadata practices.

I found this article: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en

Unfortunately, our search engine uses a hash tag instead of a question mark (nonstandard query string).

For example: http://www.site.com/search#q=search%20term

Is there a way to configure Google Analytics to recognize hash tag values in the URLs and capture these given a defined pattern?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry to say this, but hash tags won't "make it" into the reports at all, so no search reports for hash tag.

There is a simple workaround though: use **virtual pageviews**, that would emulate the request with regular query parameter with ? sign.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/search?q=search%20term']);
```

However, this virtual pageview will generate a second pageview for a given page, which isn't preferable. So I would recommend **setting up a new view specifically just for site search reports** (or try to play around with advanced filters, which might get the work done). Also, don't forget to turn on the site search within the *view settings* as you would do otherwise:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested putting in a hash into the Query Parameter field?

[image]

Comment: The problem is that is asking for parameter names. In our case, the parameter is "q". The issue is that our search tool is using a nonstandard query string. I am afraid that Google is assuming "?" here whereas this is using a hash value instead of a true query string. That's the basis of my question.